# Can I use multiple times <h1> tag one for desktop another for mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, seo

I am using bootstrap-3 ,html-5. My question is, can I use `<h1>` tag multiple times in the same page? I am using one `<h1>` for desktop and another `<h1>` for mobile. I am bit confused after searching the question. Can any one correctly suggest me the right way?

My codes are below. Are the codes SEO friendly?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
      <h1>Header in Desktop</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
      <h1>Header in Mobile</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes ofcourse, You can use multiple `h1` tags in a single page and for SEO, google has also confirmed the use of multiple `h1` tags are fine. It is valid as long as each `h1` tag is inside a  element of **html5** (except for the first `h1` on the page which does not need a specific wrapper).

Currently, Google is giving two different ranks, one rank for desktop and one rank for mobile. So having two `h1` tags are fine (one for desktop, one for mobile).

You can use your code like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
      <h1>Header in Desktop</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-*">
      <h1>Header in Mobile</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

`hidden-xs` means it will be visible on desktop, tablets and hidden on mobile.

`visible-xs-*` means it will be visible on mobile and hidden on all other devices like tablets, desktops.

Comment: Hi, can you please refer to the document where it is written?

Comment: Is it allowed when the headline on mobile and desktop are the same?

Comment: @Refilon , Yes it is allowed.

Comment: This is not true (anymore), the use of multiple h1 in html 5 (section) elements once was in the spec, later removed. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/changes.html#features-removed.